# Do I have to define a function for each new data type?

Tags: haskell, types, linear-algebra

I am using Haskell and have declared a `Vector` as

```
data Vector = Vector [Double]
```

Now, I want to declare the `dot` product of two vectors as

```
dot :: Vector -> Vector -> Double
dot a b = sum $ a * b -- I already wrote Vector as an instance of Num for *.
```

But, the problem is, I receive the error

```
Couldn't match expected type [a0] with actual type Vector
```

I assume this means that `sum` doesn't know how to operate on a `Vector`. What is the best way to approach this issue?

Comment: The product `a * b` gives a `Vector`, but `sum` takes a list. You need a converting function, like the `toList` that jozefg defines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I've noticed you're not using standard vectors. I'd suggest switching to them, but if you really don't want to,

```
 toList :: Vector -> [Double]
 toList (Vector a) = a
```

and use

```
dot a b = sum . toList $ a * b
```

If you switch to standard vectors you have 3 choices

1. Turn your `Vector` to a list,

   ```
   import Data.Vector as V
   dot a b = sum . V.toList $ a * b
   ```

   Simple, but needlessly slow.
2. Use a more general `sum`

   ```
   import Data.Foldable as F
   dot a b = F.sum $ a * b
   ```

   Flexible, can lead to weird type errors since we're relying on another typeclass.
3. Use a different, specific (the fancy word is monomorphic) `sum`

   ```
    import Data.Vector as V
    dot a b = V.sum $ a * b
   ```

   Simplest, but of course, if you stop using vectors this will break.

I'd recommend option 3, no need to be overly general yet.

Comment: Also I *believe* that the foldable method just goes through V.toList, so (3) may be much faster as well.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson Actually it appears to rely on `Data.Vector.Fusion.Stream`

Comment: Oh, nice! I hadn't looked at it in a while and had always worried about the `Foldable` instance wrecking fusion.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, yes. Oftentimes this is desirable since it allows you to prune away functions that you don't want people to have access to. For instance, giving a user `[Double]` lets them compute the length and examine it as a linked-list, while `newtype Vector = Vector [Double]` would let you expose `vectorLength` if and only if you feel it a good idea.

But that's not the problem at hand. Immediately you want to be able to operate on your `Vector` type without redefining every useful function you can think of. Fortunately, there are many ways to get past this.

You could define `Vector` as a `type` synonym instead of a new concrete type. This lets Haskell transparently interpret `Vector` as `[Double]` and use the full complement of list functions automatically

```
type Vector = [Double]

vectorSum :: Vector -> Double
vectorSum = sum
```

You could, though you were trying to avoid it, also just write your own `vectorSum` directly.

```
vectorSum :: Vector -> Double
vectorSum (Vector list) = sum list
```

Generally, it looks a little different in real code as people tend to abuse record syntax to make an easy "escape hatch" for `Vector`

```
data Vector = Vector { unVector :: [Double] }

vectorSum :: Vector -> Double
vectorSum = sum . unVector

manySums :: [Double]
manySums = map (\v -> sum (unVector v)) makeLotsOfVectors
```

You could define `Vector` as an instance of `Foldable`. `Foldable` is a typeclass and is the primary mechanism by which Haskell achieves polymorphism. In particular, you say that a type `t` is an instance of `Foldable` if you can think of it as containing elements in a particular order that can be "smashed" together. That pretty much describes a `Vector` and a `sum`, so

```
import Prelude hiding (foldl)
import Data.Foldable (Foldable, foldl, foldMap)

data Vector a = Vector [a]        -- note that the type is parametric, this is
                                  -- required for Foldable

foldableSum :: (Foldable t) => t Double -> Double
foldableSum = foldl (+) 0

instance Foldable Vector where
  foldMap f (Vector list) = foldMap f list   -- it just inherits from the 
                                             -- Foldable [] instance

vectorSum :: Vector Double -> Double
vectorSum = foldableSum
```

You can also use a very convenient mechanism of GHC Haskell called `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` to make these tedious instances happen automatically. To do this, we have to take note that `Vector` is *very* similar to `[]`---it's actually just a new name for it. That means we can use `newtype` instead of `data`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

newtype Vector a = Vector [a] deriving ( Foldable )

vectorSum :: Vector Double -> Double
vectorSum = foldl (+) 0
```

Funnily enough, there's also an extension to GHC Haskell that lets you derive `Foldable` even if you don't have a newtype. `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` is more powerful, but for `Foldable` specifically we don't need to use it.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}

data Vector a = Vector [a]

vectorSum :: Vector Double -> Double
vectorSum = foldl (+) 0
```

There's also the *very* powerful `vector` library that others have mentioned which can do all of this and MUCH much more.

Answer (score 2):

You are using sum from Prelude with type:

`sum :: Num a => [a] -> a`

sum for vectors is defined in Data.Vector (usually imported qualified)

edit: I missed the fact that you are using your own datatype, not the one from Data.Vector

Comment: Wrong vector, he's using a wrapper around `[Double]`

Comment: I guess i missed that =)

Comment: No worries so did I :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you aren't using `Data.Vector` vectors, you can't actually make `sum` work directly on your data type, since it's type is

```
sum :: Num a => [a] -> a
```

and you're giving it `Vector [Double]` instead of a `Num a => [a]`.  You'll have to extract list inside the vector first:

```
toList :: Vector -> [Double]
toList (Vector vals) = vals

dot :: Vector -> Vector -> Double
dot a b = sum . toList $ a * b
```

That being said, you should probably just use the vectors provided by `Data.Vector`, or at the very least you should define your `Vector` type as

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

import Control.Applicative

data Vector a = Vector [a] deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Functor)

instance Applicative Vector where
    pure a = Vector [a]
    (Vector fs) <*> (Vector xs) = Vector $ zipWith ($) fs xs

instance Num a => Num (Vector a) where
    a + b = (+) <$> a <*> b
    a * b = (*) <$> a <*> b
    -- etc.
```

Then you can have `Vector Int`, `Vector Double`, even `Vector (Int -> Double)`, and since it's now a `Functor` and an `Applicative`, you can do a lot more with it, as this example suggests.

Answer (score 1):

To a create a dot function you could do

```
data Vector = Vector [Double]

dot :: Vector -> Vector -> Double
dot (Vector a) (Vector b) = sum $ zipWith (*) a b
```

This way 'a' and 'b' are now the [Double] inside of the Vector and not the Vector its self.

Step-by-step:

```
dot (Vector [1,2]) (Vector [3,4]) = sum $ zipWith (*) [1,2] [3,4]

= sum $ zipWith (*) [1,2] [3,4]
= sum $ [1*3, 2*4]
= 1*3 + 2*4
= 3 + 8
= 11
```